# How to I fit a drawer into this cabinet? (Kitchen - no side panel)

Tags: kitchens, drawers

My plan is to fit a drawer into the pictured space. (Apologies for the bad photo.  It is for all intents and purposes identical to the one below but without the runners)
[image: Where I want to fit the drawer]

Based on a fixture elsewhere I have determined that I need to mount the right-hand runner to the back of the unit somehow.  There even seems to be 2 conveniently placed screw holes for just this purpose.
[image: The existing drawer that I am trying to mimic]

My questions are:

- Is this the correct, modern way to do this.
- Where (UK) do I buy such a fixture and what is it called.

I ask because I have spent >1 hour so far searching the web and cannot find a UK supplier.  I have found them in the USA but at $15-30 postage this doesn't seem viable.

Thanks

Comment: My only concern would be this backplate - usually they are not proper enough to support anything. If Yours is ok, then I would go for it.

Comment: http://www.blum.com/gb/en/04/70/35/

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure someone with better google-fu will be able to chime in with a quick link, but I too have exhausted all my usual suspects looking for what I would call a "rear mount bracket" (For example, Blum part # 295.3750.01, but only on the Blum US site.)

Anyway, a bit of bodging would have you place an L bracket against the back panel (with the caution that the back might be very thin/flimsy) and catch the drawer runner.

A long enough L bracket could go from the underside of the worktop to the runner, but you'd have to be careful that the bolt attaching the runner and the bracket doesn't interfere with the operation of the drawer.

Alternately, put a section of wood vertically beside the drawer and flush to the edge of the opening to mimic a cabinet side. You could use a couple of L brackets to hang this from the underside of the worktop and it should be more than solid enough to carry a drawer.